# Path for image file in Eclipse src folder, on a Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, path

I'm trying to load an image file.

```
File imageCheck = new File("Users/me/Documents/workspace/ChineseChess/src/RCar.gif");
if (imageCheck.exists())
    System.out.println("Image file found!");
else
    System.out.println("Image file not found! :(");
button.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Users/me/Documents/workspace/ChineseChess/src/RCar.gif"));
```

1. Should I put RCar.gif in the src or bin folder of an eclipse project?
2. How would I refer to it without the explicit path? (I'm using a mac. I believe it should be something like ~/RCar.gif but am having trouble finding the correct syntax online.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use relative paths, they are going to be relative to the project's root, or when its deployed, the directory that the jar file resides in. You can use `src/RCar.gif` as your filename.

It would be better if you created a separate folder for resources, then address them with `new File("res/RCar.gif");` Another option is to put them in the src folder and address them using the classloader.

Comment: Fixed the answer, it actually uses relative paths now :)

Answer (score 3):

If I recall correctly, Eclipse requires all resources to be placed in the resources directory.  These will be automatically bundled with your application when you export it.

At runtime, you would simply use [`Class#getResource("/path/to/your/resource")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) where the path is the location from the "resource" folder

Comment: `If I recall correctly, Eclipse requires all resources to be placed in the resources directory.` Not automatically. The folder has to be in the Eclipse build path. If you don't use a build manager like Apache Maven you can right-click on a folder and choose `Build Path / Use as Source Folder`

Comment: @Sandro Never used Eclipse, but I recall a lot of people having problems with placing resources inside the `src` folder. It was my understanding that Eclipse had a "resources" folder of some kind automatically setup

Comment: Well, the default layout of the Maven folder structure contains the "resources" folders. Sometimes the project is not set to be build automatically. In this case the resource is not copied to the Eclipse output folder that makes up the runtime resources and is thus not available at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

You can load the icon quite easily when it is in the resource folder of the class it belongs to at runtime.
See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29

Within the class `your.packagename.YourClassName` you could write the following:

```
String folderName = YourClassName.class.getName().replace('.', '/' );
String urlString = "/"+folderName+"/RCar.gif";
URL fileUri = YourClassName.class.getResource(urlString);
button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(fileUri));
```

The urlString would be `/your/packagename/YourClassName/RCar.gif`. Of course this is also where icon should be at runtime.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

yes...it takes the relative path.

public static final String FILE_PATH = "src/test/resources/car.png";