# Path for image in java eclipse on MAC OS

Tags: java, macos, file, path, swt

This is similar to [Path for image file in Eclipse src folder, on a Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398533/path-for-image-file-in-eclipse-src-folder-on-a-mac) question and i am using

```
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;


public class Images {


    static Image ICON_Search = new Image(App2.display, "src//search.jpg");
    static Image ICON_RightArrow = new Image(App2.display, "src//right2.gif");
    static Image ICON_LeftArrow = new Image(App2.display, "src//left4.gif");
    static Image Background_White=new Image(App2.display,"src//whitebg.png");
}
```

All my images are in src folder of project.This works fine on Windows but when i export it as a jar and run it on MAC OS it raises File not found exception.

Comment: Does the exported jar file contains the .jpg and .gif files?

Comment: @codeMan Yes it does.I have checked that.

Answer (score 0):

The src folder will not be exported into your Jar file. Thats just for you IDEs source code. You need to load the images as a resource:

```
Image image = new Image(App2.display,this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("search.jpg"));
```

Comment: Where should i place my images? in src folder or directly in the project folder?

Comment: As I can see you are using SWT, so your project will be packaged as a Jar? Yes place the media (images, sounds, ...) in a subpackage of your src folder, i.e.: com.company.your.projectname.resources.images. Then you need to add that path to the get resource method.

Comment: I have not used any package.All the classes are in default package.So if i put all the images in the src folder  and use "search.jpg" ,Will it work?

Comment: Guess so. But better dont use the default package. They work as a physical arrangement (like folders) and for defining the namespace of your classes.